# keybd_event printing digits instead of letters (perl win32::api)

Tags: perl, winapi

I want to print "a". Instead it prints "9". Why, and how to fix this?

```
use Win32::API;

$kbd_event = Win32::API->new(
  "user32.dll", 
  "VOID keybd_event( BYTE bVk, BYTE bScan, DWORD dwFlags, DWORD dwExtraInfo );"
);

$a = 0x61;

$kbd_event->Call( $a, 0, 0, 0 ); # press
$kbd_event->Call( $a, 0, 2, 0 ); # release
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$kbd_event->Call` is expecting a byte as its first argument but your argument is treated as an integer.

Try

```
$kbd_event->Call( chr($a), 0, 0, 0 );
$kbd_event->Call( chr($a), 0, 2, 0 );
```

Comment: Heck, I keep forgetting about bytes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

looks like the "A" key is 0x41

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Then why does `0x61` produce a `9`?

Comment: Looks like it prints first digit of decimal representation of given hex.
0x41 == 65
0x61 == 97

But why??